Adding mirrors to reflect back reverse photons of optical isolator for perfect one-way mirror?
Optical isolator passes photons in forward direction, and blocks those in reverse direction - the latter seems a waste, and e.g. in polarization-independent isolator like below we should be able add mirrors optimized to reflect these photons back to the source, getting kind of perfect one-way mirror.
Can such mirrored optical isolators (blocking in forward direction, reflecting back in reverse) be built, are they considered in literature?
For example lasers often have built-in optical isolator - adding such mirrors, they would increase the resonance cavity, not allowing photons to escape ... however, only in one time direction - could such mirrors increase laser efficiency?
Edit: mirror angles would need optimization, and similar effect could be reached with circulator.


I’m voting to close this question because it is about the availability of a product rather than the physics in the product.

@ZeroTheHero ,there was question about literature and its effect in lasers ... I don't understand these downvotes and closing, here some discussion on this topic has just developed: https://www.reddit.com/r/Optics/comments/1hl4wnm/adding_mirrors_to_reflect_back_reverse_photons_of/

this is not reddit and I did not downvote but your question is "Are such mirrored optical isolators considered in literature, available commercially?" is not about the physics of the device.  It's not a resource question, just one of commercial availability.

This is question if such enhancement is known/used, not how to buy it

Then please edit your question as it is undeniable that "Are such mirrored optical isolators considered in literature, available commercially?" refers to commercial availability.

Ok, removed - modified to "Can such mirrored optical isolators (blocking in forward direction, reflecting back in reverse) be built, are they considered in literature?"

Well… you have not really solved the core issue.  I was but one of 3 votes.  “Can they be built” is an engineering problem.  I’m still not sure what your question is: can they be built or does this increase the efficiency?  What does increase mean here?  By how much?  is 1% enough?   Anyways I’m moving on.

In reddit discussion there are concerns if it can be built, some say perfect one-way mirror would violate 2nd law of thermodynamics (?) Efficiency question is an open one, 1 percent could already be valuable.

I don't have the perfect answer but here is some theory.  All apparatus (laser cavities, spectrometers, slits, thin films/dichroics, fibres, panes of glasss) have modes, including opto isolators. Modes are the allowed paths for EM energy like photons thru the apparatus,  in general a light mode allows the transmission of complete/full wavelengths of light or multiples of the full wavelength.
In a 2 armed spectrometer somehow the light "knows" which path is most favourable and can exclusively travel that arm if it is perfectly tuned (multiple of lambda path length) and can exclusively not travel in the other arm if it is detuned (lambda +1/2 lambda path).
The best explanation of this "knowing" is EM field resonance, for example we know the EM field is everywhere, we even know that the EM field contains zero point energy.  At the speed of c a laser "knows" it cannot excite a fibre that's a mile long if it's not multiples of lambda ... but if someone trims the fibre voila the light can pass ... all due to the resonance of the EM field . One can say the EM field can begin to resonate.
With the Thor labs opto isolator its a little more complicated as using 1/2 wave plates changes the polarization .... and transmission/reflection properties of many materials depend on polarization .... so they have figured out a way to improve performance.  But in general there is no such thing as a true one way mirror.

We known angle and polarization of these reverse photons - what would prevent e.g. optimization of mirror angle to reflect them back to the lens/optical fiber? (getting looking perfect directional one-way mirror)

One can combine 2 beams if they are of differing polarization even if they are the exact same wavelength.  But if the are polarized the same it can not be done.

Sure, looks there are various ways to reflect them back, polarization can be changed with e.g. quarter wave plate ... so looks like directional perfect one-way mirror is realizable(?) But some claim it would violate 2nd law of thermodynamics (?)

Perfection is never possible in practice I think, with QM there is always a probability, i.e. 99.999999...% is never good enough. One problem withe above mirror is that the resultant beam is now of mixed polarization .... which is maybe not the desired outcome!

Sure, in practice it would be directional one-way mirror of arbitrarily high perfection - still, having a fiber optics with such one-way mirror, it would allow to transfer photons (of narrow frequencies) in only one direction ... what naively still seems in conflict with 2nd law of thermodynamics (?)
